# Migrating ASP.Net Membership

Tags: asp.net, sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I am facing problem while copying my ASP.Net Membership tables. Since I just want the schema, so I generated script without copying data.

When I access the new site, it shown

> The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database
>   schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current
>   database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to
>   either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available
>   in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a
>   newer version.

Here is the step by step I had done, which I can't get it works.

1. From source server's SSMS, right click on database.
2. Task -> Generate Scripts
3. 
4. In Choose Script Option, I clicked Next.
5. In Choose Object Type, I selected all, and click next.
6. In Choose Database Role, I selected all.
7. In Choose Schema, I selected all.
8. In Choose Stored Procedures, Choose Title, all selected.
9. Choose All View.
10. Script to new query window.
11. In destination server's SSMS, I run the scripts.
12. Tables created, which are empty.
13. I ran aspnet_regsql.exe, and the aspnet_SchemaVersions are populated.

However, the error still occur... I had run out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You need some data in the aspnet_SchemaVersion table.  Have a look at the information in the table of the database you are using and add an insert to the end of your script to add that data to the aspnet_SchemaVersion table.  I cant remember of the top of my head what's in there but its fairly simple stuff.

Here you go this should probably do it i dont think the version numbers have changed but you should check your existing db.

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘common’, 1, 1) 

INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘health monitoring’, 1, 1) 

INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘membership’, 1, 1) 

INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘personalization’, 1, 1) 

INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘profile’, 1, 1) 

INSERT INTO aspnet_SchemaVersions (Feature, CompatibleSchemaVersion, IsCurrentVersion)
VALUES(‘role manager’, 1, 1)
```

Comment: I believe there is just one line in this table.

Comment: Works for me. In my case I'm importing an empty database to SQL Azure.